# "Missing key(s) in state_dict" error when loading model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to load a model:

```
model = AlexNet3DDropoutRegression(9600)
model_save_location = 'my_model.pt'
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(model_save_location,
                                 map_location='cpu'))
```

Previously I saved it like this:

```
    torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), 
               self.cli_args.model_save_location)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Missing key(s) in state_dict: "features.0.weight", "features.0.bias", "features.1.weight", "features.1.bias", "features.1.running_mean", "features.1.running_var", "features.4.weight", "features.4.bias", "features.5.weight", "features.5.bias", "features.5.running_mean", "features.5.running_var", "features.8.weight", "features.8.bias", "features.9.weight", "features.9.bias", "features.9.running_mean", "features.9.running_var", "features.11.weight", "features.11.bias", "features.12.weight", "features.12.bias", "features.12.running_mean", "features.12.running_var", "features.14.weight", "features.14.bias", "features.15.weight", "features.15.bias", "features.15.running_mean", "features.15.running_var", "classifier.1.weight", "classifier.1.bias", "classifier.4.weight", "classifier.4.bias". 
Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "module.features.0.weight", "module.features.0.bias", "module.features.1.weight", "module.features.1.bias", "module.features.1.running_mean", "module.features.1.running_var", "module.features.1.num_batches_tracked", "module.features.4.weight", "module.features.4.bias", "module.features.5.weight", "module.features.5.bias", "module.features.5.running_mean", "module.features.5.running_var", "module.features.5.num_batches_tracked", "module.features.8.weight", "module.features.8.bias", "module.features.9.weight", "module.features.9.bias", "module.features.9.running_mean", "module.features.9.running_var", "module.features.9.num_batches_tracked", "module.features.11.weight", "module.features.11.bias", "module.features.12.weight", "module.features.12.bias", "module.features.12.running_mean", "module.features.12.running_var", "module.features.12.num_batches_tracked", "module.features.14.weight", "module.features.14.bias", "module.features.15.weight", "module.features.15.bias", "module.features.15.running_mean", "module.features.15.running_var", "module.features.15.num_batches_tracked", "module.classifier.1.weight", "module.classifier.1.bias", "module.classifier.4.weight", "module.classifier.4.bias".
```

I know I used the same version of PyTorch for saving and loading because I saved and then tried to load the model using the same Python virtual environment.

What am I doing wrong here? Below is the entire neural net.  I don't know if that helps.

```
import math

import torch.nn as nn


class AlexNet3D(nn.Module):
    def get_head(self):
        return nn.Sequential(nn.Dropout(),
                             nn.Linear(self.input_size, 64),
                             nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                             nn.Dropout(),
                             nn.Linear(64, 1),
                             )

    def __init__(self, input_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv3d(1, 64, kernel_size=(5, 5, 5), stride=(2, 2, 2), padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(64),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=3, stride=3),

            nn.Conv3d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), stride=(1, 1, 1), padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=3, stride=3),

            nn.Conv3d(128, 192, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(192),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(192, 192, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(192),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Conv3d(192, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=1),
            nn.BatchNorm3d(128),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=3, stride=3),
        )

        self.classifier = self.get_head()

        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                n = m.kernel_size[0] * m.kernel_size[1] * m.out_channels
                m.weight.data.normal_(0, math.sqrt(2. / n))
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm3d):
                m.weight.data.fill_(1)
                m.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, x):
        xp = self.features(x)
        x = xp.view(xp.size(0), -1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return [x, xp]
```

Comment: It LOOKS like a version mismatch.  How did you save the `my_model.pt` originally?

Comment: Yes, I did save it originally.

Comment: I didn't ask if you did, I asked HOW you saved it.

Comment: I added that to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the following conditional when saving the model:

```
    if isinstance(self.model, torch.nn.DataParallel):
        self.model = self.model.module
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Tim Roberts, this is likely to be a version mismatch between the code used to produce `my_model.pt` and the one used to create your `AlexNet3DDropoutRegression` model.

A state dict is just a dictionary, with layer names as keys and layer parameters as values. Thus, the issue here is that layer names are different in the saved state_dict and the model you created.

It is often possible, given that it is only a naming problem without any changes to the architecture, to convert the state dict, for example by creating a new dictionary with corrected keys and values coming from the previous state_dict. In your case, the new layer name would be the old one without the `module.` prefix.

But be careful, it is possible that some layers in both the model and the state dict have this `module.` prefix, and in this case you should not change the name of such layers. I also did not verify whether all your missing keys have a corresponding unexpected key in the list.

Comment: If you don't care about model weights, then you can use the model you created without loading any state_dict initially, and use randomly initialized weights before training

Comment: I see something that might be an issue for what you are trying to do. You have 2 classes, `AlexNet3D` and `AlexNet3DDropoutRegression`. How are they related ? Are you saving the state_dict of one and loading it to the other ?